Umbrella Policy for Greater Than Half Million Worth
My net worth is around 1.4 million dollars. I read somewhere that I should get an umbrella policy. Currently, I have basic car insurance as shown below.
Car 1 Coverage:
Bodily Injury Coverage
Limit Per Accident $60,000
Limit Per Person $30,000
Property Damage Coverage
Limit Per Accident $25,000
Car 2 Coverage:
Bodily Injury Coverage
Limit Per Accident $60,000
Limit Per Person $30,000
Property Damage Coverage
Limit Per Accident $25,000
Other Than Collision Deductible
Deductible $500
Collision Coverage
Deductible $500
Uninsured/Underinsured Motor Vehicle Coverage
Limit Per Accident $60,000
Limit Per Person $30,000
Uninsured/Underinsured Property Damage (under Uninsured/Underinsured BIPD) Coverage
Limit Per Accident $25,000
Personal Injury Protection Coverage
Aggregate Limit $2,500
Car insurance + home is through State Farm.
Should I increase bodily injury coverage? To how much and on which cars? Also how much should I get the umbrella policy worth and how much does it usually cost per month?

Have you talked to your insurance agent?

@littleadv Not yet. I am sure they will try to sell me the most expensive policy. That is why I am asking here to get some sense of it.

Remember that you don't need to protect any assets that you included in the $1.4MM by an umbrella policy if they are in retirement accounts (IRA, 401K, etc.). Those accounts are not subject to forfeiture to creditors on debt resulting from lawsuits that would be covered by an umbrella policy.

Umbrella comes on top of your specific liability policies and usually covers only beyond maximum liability coverage for these policies. Talk to an agent.

Thanks I will talk to the agent and report back.

See past "related" questions for explanation of what an umbrella policy can do for you. Yes, it will be secondary to your main liability coverage and require that you max that out first.  Perhaps it should be called "safety net against being sued into/past bankruptcy" rather than umbrella.

Retirement accounts like 401k’s are protected by federal law (ERISA) from damages, but IRAs are covered by state laws that vary from state to state.  This is one reason to delay rolling your accounts over to an IRA when you retire.  In any case, your net worth doesn’t determine your potential liability.  If you cause a wreck at a meeting of the Ferrari  collectors association you could easily do millions of dollars of damage that would be in excess of your net worth and the amount of your umbrella coverage…

That coverage seems a bit low to me. I could be wrong though.

I'd consider the nature of your net worth and your locale's laws.  An umbrella policy may not be necessary.  Many states will not allow a primary home or retirement plan to be seized in a civil action.  So if you have a home with 800K equity, and a 500K 401K, and a 100k between a brokerage and savings, really only 100K needs to be protected.
Its worth consulting a lawyer over this.
A great first step is to increase your liability coverage on both cars to the max.  And I would recommend doing this, today, for both bodily and property.  This just makes sense for a person with some kind of wealth.
